# Relationship between keytab and spn [Kerberos]

Tags: spring-security, kerberos, spnego

Recently I'm doing some experiment with AD and Spring Security Kerberos. I'm not sure is this a bug or did I mis-configured some settings.

I have 2 domains (domain1 and domain2). Domain1 and domain2 are not in the same forest and doesn't have any trust between them.

Domain1 has a spn (HTTP/test-server.domain1.org). Another HTTP application running on a different server has a keytab generated in domain1 and this tie to the spn we have earlier.

In domain2, I added the same spn I have for domain1 (HTTP/test-server.domain1.org) into it. On the other hand, I have a win7 client that's a member of domain2, and when I tried to do a SSO to the HTTP application, it allows me to go through. Could this be a security issue? Because It seems that the keytab I have in the HTTP application is generated in domain1 and tied to a user in domain1 as well.

Comment: Are you sure about this: "In domain2, I added the same spn I have for domain1 (HTTP/test-server.domain1.org) into it."? It sounds very confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I know it does sounds a bit confusing. I've tried simplifying it as best I could. I'm sure that "In domain2, I added the same spn I have for domain1"

Comment: The thing that I don't understand is how can the service (Using keytab generated from domain1) validate the ticket I send and received through domain2.

Comment: You haven't told us, is this a web application that you have built? Where is it hosted? What security mechanism are you using? We can't very well tell you if it is a security vulnerability if we don't know what you are trying to do, or how you are trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a keytab file, you are using Kerberos, against AD like you stated. You generate the keytab and map it and the SPN to a user account on the domain, that is used to query AD. You have to note that when Kerberos authentication fails, browsers fall back to the next authentication mechanism by priority. In this case, it would be NTLM, which is a Microsoft authentication mechanism that they are phasing out as it is less secure, but it can easily and automatically pass windows logon credentials to a web server. This could and likely will explain the behavior that you are seeing.